# Turn a landscape upside down

Tags: 3d-view

I managed to create a landscape in blender using ANT Landscape and now I want to turn it upside down..How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Scale it by a factor on `-1`in the Z axis with `S` > `Z` > `-1`

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other thing you could do is select your mesh (landscape), and press R -> X -> 180 -> Enter. I would recommend doing this in edit mode, so that the rotation will be pre-applied.